# jQuery css friendly form controls

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I found a lot of jQuery plugins that make html form controls editable with css.

Can someone recommend one over the other

(one plugin per answer please, so users can vote)

Comment: how do I make this community wiki?

Comment: Flag it for a moderator to make it community wiki, @Teddy - that's no longer an option :)